FreeRadius - EAP-TLS problems with Windows computer certificates
Recently we wanted to implement Freeradius with EAP-TLS verification. On Windows, when we install certificate for current user, everything is fine.
Main problem occurs when we try to install certificate for whole computer (we want all computer users to have access to network using the same certificate). When we do that, Windows adds a "host/" before User-Name. This creates difference between username that EAP gets from user and one in certificate. Without line "check_cert_cn = %{User-Name}" in EAP config file (mods-enabled/eap) it works, but we want to maintain that verification (without it user could login as any username from "users" file, which isn't a problem). I feel like we're missing something obvious.
We've searched documentation, forums and Freeradius mail lists for few days, but found no answer for this specific problem.
We've tried:

setting up preprocessing that would delete "host/" from User-Name - we're getting error "Identity does not match User-Name, setting from EAP Identity"
adding local proxy with realm "host/" - the same error as previous attempt
manually adding "host/" to name during certificate creation - resulted in "host/host/username"

